# How do disable 'Alt Tab' shortcut on RHEL 7 With KDE?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, kde, alt-tab

How can you disable the 'Alt Tab' short cut on RHEL7 with KDE programmatically?

I have a Java app that when run needs to prevent the user from using the 'Alt Tab' shortcut. Therefore, I would like to disable it. I have looked into gsettings but haven't succeeded with it. Could gsettings be the wrong tool because it is only for gnome?

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!